# React - Create multiple useRefs in one line using object or array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-ref

I want to declare multiple useRefs and have them all in 1 object or an array. If that's not possible, then any means of declaring multiple refs in one line, like array destructuring

I tried these so far, neither worked.

attempt 1

```
const inputRefs = useRef({ input1: null, input2: null, input3: null, input4: null })

function focusInput() {
    inputRefs.input2.current.focus()
}

return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input1} />
        <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input2} />
        <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input3} />
        <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input4} />
        <button onClick={focusInput}>focus</button>
    </div>
)
```

attempt 2

```
const [input1, input2, input3, input4] = Array(4).fill(useRef(null))

function focusInput() {
    input2.current.focus()
}

return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" ref={input1} />
        <input type="text" ref={input2} />
        <input type="text" ref={input3} />
        <input type="text" ref={input4} />
        <button onClick={focusInput}>focus</button>
    </div>
)
```

note I only have 4 inputs in the example, but in reality I have much more so hence I want to find a way. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kk I found a similar way to my first one but it works. Further suggestions are also welcome

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const inputRefs = {input1: useRef(null), input2: useRef(null), input3: useRef(null), input4: useRef(null)}

  function focusInput() {
    inputRefs.input2.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input1} />
      <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input2} />
      <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input3} />
      <input type="text" ref={inputRefs.input4} />
      <button onClick={focusInput}>focus</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [react-use-refs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-refs) it used a clever generator to create how many `useRef` you need.

```js
import useRefs from "react-use-refs";

function Demo() {
    const [someRef, anotherRef] = useRefs();
    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={someRef}>someRef</div>
            <div ref={anotherRef}>anotherRef</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or you can implement one yourself

```js
import {useRef} from "react";

const MAX_ITERATIONS_COUNT = 50;

function iterator() {
    return this;
}

export default function useRefs(...args) {
    let count = 0;

    return {
        next() {
            if (++count > MAX_ITERATIONS_COUNT) {
                throw new Error(
                    "useMultipleRefs: reached more than 50 refs. This hook can be used exclusively with the array destructuring syntax."
                );
            }

            return {
                done: false,
                value: useRef(args[count - 1] ?? args.at(-1)),
            };
        },
        [Symbol.iterator]: iterator,
    };
}
```

Or using my version from that collection here [`npm i @perymimon/react-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@perymimon/react-hooks)

```js
import {useRefs} from @perymimon/react-hooks
// or 
import useRefs from @perymimon/react-hooks/src/useRefs
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to correct.

1. The `useRef` is a react hook (which should be defined in the top level of the function). Therefore, to create refs and store them in an array, you should use `createRef`.
2. [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) does not create 4 new refs instead of that share a single `ref`. That's why even though you clicked on the button always last input is always referred to. To get rid of that, use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) like below.

```
import { createRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [input1, input2, input3, input4] = Array.from({ length: 4 }, () =>
    createRef(null)
  );

  function focusInput() {
    input2.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={input1} />
      <input type="text" ref={input2} />
      <input type="text" ref={input3} />
      <input type="text" ref={input4} />
      <button onClick={focusInput}>focus</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit gracious-varahamihira-r620j4]

Answer (score 0):

You can set *ref* on your inputs wrapper and work with inputs through DOM API.

```
const containerRef = useRef(null);

function focusInput() {
    const containerNode = containerRef.current;
    containerNode.childNodes[2].focus();
}

return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <button onClick={focusInput}>focus</button>
    </div>
)
```